# Fill pandas column using values from list

Tags: python, pandas

This is my list:

```
my_list = [
2002-01-11 22:15:00, 
2002-02-12 10:30:00, 
2002-03-14 02:30:00, 
2002-04-12 22:15:00
]
```

I have DataFrame:

```
                 dt_object         diff
0      2002-01-01 00:00:00   -160.95041
1      2002-01-01 00:15:00   -160.81016
2      2002-01-01 00:30:00   -160.66989
3      2002-01-01 00:45:00   -160.52961
4      2002-01-01 01:00:00   -160.38930
```

I want to create new column 'Hit' with False value by default and True value when dates from list match.

Expected output:

```
                 dt_object         diff   hit
0      2002-01-01 00:00:00   -160.95041   False
1      2002-01-01 00:15:00   -160.81016   False
2      2002-01-01 00:30:00   -160.66989   False
3      2002-01-01 00:45:00   -160.52961   False
4      2002-01-01 01:00:00   -160.38930   False
....................
....................
1010      2002-01-11 22:15:00   -150.54678   True
```

because 2002-01-11 22:15:00 is in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
import numpy as np
df['hit'] = np.where(df['dt_object'].isin(my_list),1,0)) # will give 1 or 0 according if the condition is satisfied.
```

To just get back `True` or `False`, just remove the returning part.

```
df['hit'] = df['dt_object'].isin(my_list)
```

Comment: you don't need numpy where in second option

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
df['hit'] = df['dt_object'].isin(my_list)
```